# DevExpress eXpressApp Framework and eXpress Persistent Objects : Sort column issue

Tags: devexpress, xaf, xpo

I am not able to sort column for NonPersistent column. (DevExpress eXpressApp Framework (XAF) and eXpress Persistent Objects (XPO) )
Here my code

```
[Association("PCs-Gs", typeof(Allotments))]
public XPCollection<Allotments> PCs
{
    get { return GetCollection<Allotments>("PCs"); }
}

[Association("SCs-Gs", typeof(Allotments))]
public XPCollection<Allotments> SCs
{
     get { return GetCollection<Allotments>("SCs"); }
}

XPCollection<Allotments> _allAllotmentsCore;
public XPCollection<Allotments> AllAllotments
{
    get
         {
            if (_allAllotmentsCore == null)
               {
                _allAllotmentsCore = new XPCollection<Allotments>(Session);
               }
               _allAllotmentsCore.Criteria = CriteriaOperator.Parse("PCGrower.Oid == ? OR SCGrower.Oid == ?", Oid);
               _allAllotmentsCore.Sorting.Add(new SortProperty("Project.ProjectName", SortingDirection.Descending));

                PopulateCollection(_allAllotmentsCore);
                return _allAllotmentsCore;
        }
}

private void PopulateCollection(XPCollection<Allotments> sourceCollection)
{
            sourceCollection.AddRange(PCs);
            sourceCollection.AddRange(SCs);
}
```

Now properties

```
[PersistentAlias("PCs[Project is not null].Count")] // THIS IS WORKING
//[PersistentAlias("AllAllotments[PCs.Project is not null].Count")] // THIS IS NOT WORKING
 public int myCustomProperties 
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(EvaluateAlias("myCustomProperties")); }
    }
```

IF use PersistentAlias on NonPersistent column then  I can able to sort this column. For that, I need to add logic on PersistentAlias.

In My Case:

I need to add this logic on PersistentAlias like [PersistentAlias('whole logic')]

LOgic

```
public int myCustomProperties 
    {
                get
                {
                    int _myCustomProperties  = 0;
                    Projects project = null;
                    foreach (Allotments obj in AllAllotments)
                    {
                        if (project != obj.Project && obj.Project != null)
                        {
                            project = obj.Project;
                            _myCustomProperties += 1;
                        }
                    }
                    return _myCustomProperties  ;
                }
    }
```

Let focus on logic

I have use AllAllotments (this not Association properties).

If I use like [PersistentAlias('use AllAllotments')] then I got error.

But I use like [PersistentAlias("use  PCs")] then working.

Only different: PCs (Association properties) and AllAllotments (not Association ).

SO, MY Question:

How I can use AllAllotments on PersistentAlias ?

Anyone idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a free join. From the DevExpress docs.

> With XPO, you can build criteria based on persistent objects that are
>   not directly related (don't have explicitly defined associations)
>   using Free Joins. In essence, XPO allows you to join any persistent
>   objects on a condition, calculate aggregate functions against matching
>   objects using their properties, and return aggregate values as the
>   result of joining. To accomplish this, use JoinOperands in your
>   criteria.

You can either use them in criteria, e.g.,

```
CriteriaOperator criteria = 
CriteriaOperator.Parse("[<Orders>][^.EmployeeID = EmployeeID].Count() > 50");
XPCollection<Employee> employees = new XPCollection<Employee>(session, criteria);
```

Or you can use them within `[PersistentAlias]`. See [this item from the DevExpress support center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T308889).

```
public class Department : BaseObject 
{
     private System.Int32? _TotalPhoneNumbers;
     [PersistentAlias("[<PhoneNumber>][Party.<Contact>Department.Oid = ^.Oid and PhoneType='1'].Count()")]
     public System.Int32? TotalPhoneNumbers {
        get {
            if (_TotalPhoneNumbers == null) {
                _TotalPhoneNumbers = (int?)EvaluateAlias("TotalPhoneNumbers");
            }
            return _TotalPhoneNumbers;
        }
    }
}
```

With all things DevExpress, the best place to ask is their [support center](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/).